# what does happen when an pointer to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue

Please consider following scenario.
//getString() function definition

```
std::string getString()
{
 return "Hello!";
}
```

In code we write following.

```
const char* p = getString().c_str();
```

This code compiles without any error.
Questions:

1. We are getting a pointer to an rvalue here. Is this valid?
2. If yes, what is the scope which `p` is valid.?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Comment: In a hilariously ironic twist, changing the signature to `const char* getString()` would be valid, as you'd then get a pointer to a `static` string literal.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure about the duplicate. It's the same context, but this question is very specific. Does `c_str()` return an rvalue? The proposed duplicate and it's answers makes no mention of value categories.

Comment: @George Minor correction: yes, but no for all practical purposes. it's valid, but `p` is only valid until its initialisation is complete (after which the temporary object is destroyed), so it's completely useless.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This question uses incorrect wording, but it should be clear what is meant, and if adjusting for what is meant, it is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @hvd The fact that we disagree on what is meant shows that it's *not* clear what is meant. I would propose taking the question at face value rather than assuming intent. If the question's phrasing doesn't make sense, then clarifying what it is about it that doesn't make sense would be the proper course of action.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There is no such thing as a pointer to an rvalue. If we take the question literally, the question should simply be closed as unclear. The duplicate is because NathanOliver used common sense in figuring out what was meant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm pretty sure the dupe will answer the OP's question.  If not they can ping me.  If you disagree feel free to reopen it but I stand by my vote.

Comment: @NathanOliver And I'm not confident enough in my opinion to reopen it unilaterally. I just thought it was worth a second look. And it seems people in the comments agree it's a duplicate.

Comment: taking the question literally, the answer is: no you are not taking a pointer to an rvalue (you cannot in general), you are just storing the pointer returned by `c_str` called on an rvalue which is covered by the dupe

Comment: @George that sounds interesting - do you have a link to any documentation explaining that phenomenon?

Comment: @Default A string literal exists for the entire duration of the program. A pointer to a string literal will be valid forever.

Comment: @Default [CPP ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) explains the semantics of string literals in c++ :). (I should of also mentioned in my other comment that you'd also need to remove `.c_str()` from the assignment for obvious reasons)